# Co-relational algorithms to find relationship between datasets

Tags: algorithm, correlation

My problem statement is "How to find co-relation between fields"

Let me explain it by an example:

Suppose I have a dataset which contains room temperature and CPU speed after regular intervals of time. i.e. two fields, one is room temperature and other one is CPU speed. As we know that CPU speed increases with rise in external temperature. So, there lies a relationship between room-temperature and CPU speed, as a result computer's performance decreases.

I want such an algorithm which may tell me relationship between two fields whether they are directly proportional to each other or inversely and what happens with third parameter (computer's performance) with change in other two parameters (room-temperature and CPU speed). Please tell me if you know some sort of algorithm to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but a simple linear regression would work.

[Wikipedia article on linear regressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)

For example in R you would use lm function :

```
lm(formula = cpuSpeed ~ roomTemp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Linear regression is a common approach, but you should also take the time to plot the two variables against each other.  This visualization will help you discover nonlinear relationships as well